# Missing outer wall on some layers?

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, z-axis

It seems there are some missing lines on the outer wall on the Z-axis with my prints. I'm not able to pinpoint the problem. Does anyone have ideas about what might be wrong with my setup/settings?

Example:

[image: Printed model with printing errors highlighted]

Here are some settings that I think are relevant:
Printer: Ender 3 v1
Filament: Das Filament
Slicer: Cura

- Hotend temp: 215 °C
- Layer height: 0.2 mm
- Wall speed: 30 mm/s
- Travel speed: 200 mm/s
- Retraction distance: 6.5 mm
- Combing mode: not in skin (Max comb: 30)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case others are interested in the solution, after playing with various settings, increasing the nozzle temperature fixed the issue. Using 217-218 I'm able to get a decent surface now.

Comment: I had to raise temperatures and turn off enclosure fans during Winter because the room temperature around the 3D printer is colder.

Comment: If this solved the problem, your extruder is just marginally able to push a sufficient amount of material through the hotend at the speed and temperature you're at. Normally I would expect an Ender 3 to do somewhat better than that, so you may have other underlying problems I'll try to address in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The OP solved the problem by increasing temperature from 210 to "217-218". While it's good to have it working now, this likely suggests other problems with the printer thaat should be investigated.

If the change in temperature made the difference to get this print working, your extruder is just marginally able to push a sufficient amount of material through the hotend at the speed and temperature you're at. Normally I would expect an Ender 3 to do somewhat better, even with the stock extruder and hotend. Here are a few things you might want to check:

- Is the filament properly dried? If it's absorbed moisture, the vapor phase transition will absorb **at lot** of heat from the hotend, making the effective extrusion temperature significantly lower than the block temperature. In my experience, it behaves like it's 20-25 ˚C lower than what you have it set to. You can kinda compensate for this by increasing the temperature (keeping an eye not to go over the safe temperature for the PTFE lining, max of about 250 ˚C) but the right solution if this is your problem is to dry your filament.
- Is anything mechanically wrong with the extruder? A crack in the tension arm or weak spring can leave it very underpowered.
- Are the extruder hob gear teeth clogged with plastic shavings? This will also leave it underpowered.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm rather new to 3d printing (2+ year) though I think there are definitely two factors that contributed to this problem: 1. The filament, I don't need to increase the temp that much with my Creality filaments, so there is something wrong with Das Filament brand (it's new our of box). 2. The weather is getting much colder now so the room temperature is much lower